# Continually stream with just algebra in Scala

Tags: scala, scalaz, algebra, scala-cats

Would it be possible to define a continuous stream of the same element with just algebra?

If I look at the implementation of Streams in Scala I see the following method definition:

`def continually[A](elem: => A): Stream[A] = cons(elem, continually(elem))`

Look at `Cons` you can see that it's just a tuple with a head element and a tail.

`final class Cons[+A](hd: A, tl: => Stream[A]) extends Stream[A]`

I'm having difficulties of creating this `Cons` class with just algebra.

```
def continually[A, G[_]](a: => A): G[A] = {
  ???
}
```

The above is not enough, because I need a different type, let's call it `B` that represents `Cons` in a way that it allows a `head` and a `tail`, but that also extends itself (`Stream` or in this case `G[_]`).

```
def continually[A, G[_], B <: G](a: => A): B = {
  ???
}
```

My first naive implementation is as follows:

```
def continually[A, G[_], B <: G[A]](a: => A)
                                   (implicit pureB: (A, G[A]) => B): B = {
  pureB(a, continually[A, G, B](a))
}

// Run
implicit def pureStream[A](head: A, tail: Stream[A]) = cons(head, tail)
continually[Int, Stream, Cons[Int]](1)
```

But this is of course not lazy.

My second attempt is making the tail lazy and it works as expected:

```
def continually[A, G[_], B <: G[A]](a: => A)
                                   (implicit pureB: (A, => G[A]) => B): B = {
  println("[continually called]")
  pureB(a, continually[A, G, B](a))
}

implicit def pureStream[A](head: A, tail: => Stream[A]) = cons(head, tail)

val result = Source
  .fromIterator(() => continually[Int, Stream, Cons[Int]](1).toIterator)
  .throttle(1, 1.second)
  .runWith(Sink.foreach(println))

result.onComplete(_ => println("*** Finished ***"))
```

Which results in the output below:

```
[continually called]
[continually called]
1
[continually called]
1
[continually called]
1
[continually called]
1
[continually called]
1
[continually called]
1
[continually called]
1
[continually called]
1
[continually called]
1
```

So my question now is as follows:

Instead of explicitly asking for a `implicit pureB: (A, => G[A]) => B`, is there any other way to ask for an applicative that can instantiate a tuple? I can't use `implicit applicativeB: Applicative[B]`, because B is not aware that is supposed to be a tuple with a lazy tail.

My idea was to create a new type definition for `B` where it is now aware that it is a tuple with a lazy tail.

`B <: (A, => G[A]): G[A]`

However this is now allowed by the compiler:

```
Error:(77, 39) no by-name parameter type allowed here
    def continually[A, G[_], B <: (A, => G[A]): G[A]](a: => A)
```

Any idea on how I can create something of `B` that is supposed to be a tuple and at the same time trying to lean on stuff that is already there in `Cats` or `Scalaz`?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `Stream.continually(1)` or `lazy val stream: Stream[Int] = 1 #:: stream`? Both create a lazy, infinite stream containing only that one element.

Comment: I'm aware of the `Stream.continually`. My question is not about "how to create an infinite stream of Integers", but "how would I define an algebra that makes this possible, without relying on concrete types".

Comment: In Scala terminology, `Cons` is not a `Tuple`. As for your last definition of `B`, I think you need to use `=>`: `B <: (A, => G[A]) => G[A]` compiles for me.